# read xml file using http

Tags: java, xml

Is anyone aware of a quick way of reading in an xml file over http?
(e.g. i have a file located in http://www.abc.com/file.xml). How can i read this file from a java app

All help is greatly appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `java.net.URL` to get an `InputStream`:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://www.abc.com/file.xml");
final InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
// Read the input stream as usual
```

Exception handling and stuff omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 3):

Dave Ray's answer is indeed quick and easy, but it won't work well with HTTP redirects or if you for example have to go through a proxy server that requires authentication. Unfortunately, the standard Java API's classes (in java.net) lack some functionality or are hard to use in such circumstances.

The open source library [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html) can handle redirects automatically and make it easy to work with proxy servers that require authentication.

Here's a basic example:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://www.abc.com/file.xml");

int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
}

byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
```

Comment: Thanks Jesper. The server that houses the xml is under my control so I dont have to worry about redirects. Thanks though for your valid input, its much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using the W3C DOM and aren't interested in any of the IO or HTTP details you can do the following:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

...

final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document document = builder.parse("http://www.abc.com/file.xml");
```